# Unmarshmaling json to nested struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I have different json byte inputs that I need to unmarshal into a nested json structure. I am able to unmarshal the json into the struct App. However I am unable to add to "status" struct.

I tried to unmarshal, but that doesnt work since my app1 & app2 are of type App instead of bytes. And trying to set directly gives the error "cannot use app1 (type App) as type []App in assignment"

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type App struct {
    Appname string `json:"appname"`
    Builds  string `json:"builds"`
}

type Status struct {
    Apps []App `json:"apps"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData1 := []byte(`
            {  
               "appname": "php1",
               "buildconfigs":"deleted"
            }
        `)

    jsonData2 := []byte(`
            {  
               "appname": "php2",
               "buildconfigs":"exists"
            }
        `)

    // unmarshal json data to App
    var app1 App
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData1, &app1)

    var app2 App
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData2, &app2)

    var status Status
    //json.Unmarshal(app1, &status)
    //json.Unmarshal(app2, &status)

    status.Apps = app1
    status.Apps = app2

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(app1))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(app1))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign single element to array field so convert your

```
status.Apps = app1
status.Apps = app2
```

to something like

```
status.Apps = []App{app1, app2}
```

or

```
status.Apps = []App{}
status.Apps = append(status.Apps, app1)
status.Apps = append(status.Apps, app2)
```

Also your JSON field named `buildconfigs` and in struct specification `json:"builds"`. Structure's field always will be empty in this case.

Working example http://play.golang.org/p/fQ-XQsgK3j

Comment: Thanks. I think status.Apps = append(status.Apps, app1) works for my use case as I can invoke it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing to me :s But if you modify your JSON data to an JSON array and it will work with `Unmarshal` and could be unmarshal to status with no problems:

```
func main() {
    jsonData1 := []byte(`
            {  
               "apps": [{
                   "appname": "php1",
                   "buildconfigs":"deleted"
                },{  
                   "appname": "php2",
                   "buildconfigs":"exists"
                }]
            }
        `)

    var status Status
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData1, &status)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", status)
}
```

Working example here: http://play.golang.org/p/S4hOxJ6gHz

Comment: That is true. But I am getting the app information from another package. And I need to build the struct for status for multiple calls.