# Get value of key in json struct unmarshalled

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

First of all, I have read a lot of questions, I only find two similar questions but I can't add a comment (reputation):

[Unmarshmaling json to nested struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350730/unmarshmaling-json-to-nested-struct)

[Casting interface{} to struct in json encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409665/casting-interface-to-struct-in-json-encoding)

I attach you my go code:
[I want to extract each value](https://play.golang.org/p/YFP0Y4QJAv)

I don't know how I can get each value and to store it in a different variable like this:

```
music_type := ...
fmt.Println(music_type) // Rock
```

Can somebody help me please ?

Thank you!

Comment: `music_type := values.Type[0].Music.Type` didn't work?

Comment: Perfectly! Thank you @Flimzy.